# Calculate zonal statistics in R as in GIS

Tags: r, raster

I have multiple rasters in a folder. I need to extract mean of each of these rasters over a polygon shape file (has more 2500 polygons).

I came across two functions `zonal` and `extract`. It says extract can be used for points, lines and polygons too. Is it the only difference ? (Yes/No expected)

How can I extract mean from these multiple rasters and specify different column names as per their filenames for these extracted mean values ?

Edit::

I found a code somewhere and implemented it. But it is taking forever and no progress at all.

```
grids <- list.files("my_path", pattern = "*.tif$")

#check the number of files in the raster list (grids)
length <- length(grids)

#read-in the polygon shapefile
poly <- readShapePoly("my_path/supplimentY.shp")

#create a raster stack
s <- stack(paste0("my_path/", grids))

#extract raster cell count (sum) within each polygon area (poly)
for (i in 1:length(grids)){
  ex <- extract(s, poly, fun='mean', na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE, weights = TRUE)
# the code doesnot progress from here onwards. 
# i checked it by adding this line:: print(i)

}

#write to a data frame
dfr <- data.frame(ex)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need the loop (you repeat the same operation at each iteration!).

It should be like this:

```
library(terra)   
ff <- list.files("my_path", pattern = "\\.tif$", full=TRUE)
s <- rast(ff)

poly <- vect("my_path/supplimentY.shp")
ex <- extract(s, poly, fun='mean', na.rm=TRUE)
#or  ex <- extract(s, poly, fun='mean', na.rm=TRUE, exact=TRUE)
```

You can also use `terra::zonal`

With the (now obsolete) "raster" package you can do

```
library(raster)   
ff <- list.files("my_path", pattern = "\\.tif$", full=TRUE)
s <- stack(ff)
poly <- shapefile("my_path/supplimentY.shp")
ex <- extract(s, poly, fun='mean', na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE, weights = TRUE)
```

Comment: I have stacked 15 rasters and run the code as you suggested. It is taking forever. I don't know what's going on inside, R is just busy. Shapefile has 2796 polygons. When done the same in QGIS it would normally take 2 mins for each raster. Is it normal for extract function to take so much time ? I believe R must be much faster.

Comment: did you read my comment ? and my question regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006421/calculate-zonal-statistics-in-r-using-extract-function-of-raster-package

Comment: It is slow. The next version of raster (currently in the CRAN approval pipeline) should increase speed significantly.

Comment: You can try `exactexctract` for faster calculations https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr

Comment: Yes, or `terra::zonal` or `terra::extract`

Answer (score -1):

I used the same code to calculate the zonal mean of climatology for an area boundary, it took me 5-6mins to work on 2736 layers of raster data.

```
    layers <- length(clim)
        for (i in 1:length(clim)) {
     ex <- extract(clim, shpwb, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE)
     }

     df <- data.frame(ex)

     write.csv(df, file = "E:/Central University of Jharkhand/3rd Semester/Climatology/R Studio/CSV.csv")
```